# mysql join one to many relationship and print in different rows

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table for example `citations` that contains:

```
paperkey 
1
2
```

and another table `source` that contains

```
paperkey | authors
1          a
1          b
1          c
2          d
2          e
3          x
5          y 
6          z
6          a
```

The `paperkey` in table `citation` is the subset of `paperkey` in `source` table. So I need to take the `authors` of `paperkey` in table citation. My expected output is:

```
1          a
1          b
1          c
2          d
2          e
```

I tried but I could not find the relevant query. Currently I have the query:

```
select a.paperkey, groupconcat(b.authors)
from citations a
left join source b
on a.paperkey = b.paperkey
group by a.paperkey;
```

but the result is

```
1         a,b,c
2         d,e
```

This is the best I could do. But I needed to produce the output I expected so that the authors are printed in different rows and I could not find any query that works like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to have the need to group the results, you should just need to order the results like this:

```
select a.paperkey, b.authors
from citations a
left join source b using(paperkey)
order by b.paperkey, b.authors;
```

I personally would us using, since the column names are the same.